# Cloud-code request.user is null when called from one activity, but not the previous one

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

When trying to get the user object in a cloude-code function, the request.user object is null but only when called from a certain activity. The app consists of three acitvities: Login, main, and the activity calling the function. If I call it from the main activity, request.user gives us the user as expected, but it is null when called from the third activity.

The login code: Starts the main activity on success.

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(uName, uPassword, new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
        if (parseUser != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser().isAuthenticated()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This code runs fine, we get logged in and sent onwards.
The main activity code is way too long to post here, and the relevant part is just "statActivity(intent);", but if anyone is curious: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nuvwTSY7)

The function calling the auth function. When running from main, request.user becomes the user, when running from the third activity (contaning only this function and basic android stuff), it's suddenly null.

```
public void onNewRandomGameClick(View v) {
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("testUserAuth", new HashMap<String, Object>());
    finish();
}
```

Lastly, the serverside code. Again, works from one activity and not the other.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("testUserAuth", function(request, response) {
    console.log("Testing user authencation...");
    if(request.user){
        response.success();
        console.log("We are authorized");
    } else {
        response.error("Authentication failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Try calling `finish();` only when the function call has returned (on callback)

Comment: Did unfortunately not work. I have however managed to pinned it down to something after mainactivitys "onCreate", since it works up untill after that.

Comment: I am having exact same problem when i upgraded to Parse SDK 1.9.4. When i moved back to SDK 1.8.0 all works fine.

Comment: Not that I like the idea of using an old version, but where can I grab 1.8.0?

Comment: just switched to 1.9.0 and I no longer get this error: https://parse.com/downloads/android/Parse/1.9.0